# Monacaのアプリの審査時にpush通知に関することでゆるい編集が依頼されました

Tags: ios, monaca

> Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. （略）
>   You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the API.

これはどういうことでしょうか。
私はpush通知に関してはなにも実装しておりません

Answer (score 2):

> You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning.

どうやらこれ自体は単なる形式的な警告のようです。

審査時に毎回この警告が出るのを回避したければ、対象となるAPIを削れという話です。

> 私はpush通知に関してはなにも実装しておりません

あなたが利用しているMonacaその他のフレームワークが対象APIを含んでいる場合でも警告されます。